# Get server name from PostConstruct method in a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If I had an instance of `HttpServletRequest`, I could do `request.getServerName()` to get the server name. However, during the post initialization of the controller beans, I have no instance of `HttpServletRequest`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/data"})
public class DataController {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // how to get server name?
    }
}
```

How do I get the server name in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no good ways to do it.

Generally speaking, server doesn't know the name that can be used to access it from the outside. Actually, `HttpServletRequest.getServerName()` isn't a solution either, because it returns a name used to send that particular request, not the canonical name you want your server to be known under.

The typical solution is to configure the canonical server name for a particular deployment in a property file, etc.

Comment: You are right. There is no way the servlet container can know its server name until there is a request. Thanks.