# Get host and contextroot in class without HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, contextpath

I´m currently creating a class for handling sending of mails. For some of these mails I need to construct links (account activation, reset password, confirmations etc).

I don´t want to hardcode the host of the links, as the host will be different for dev, test and prod. So I need to get the hostname and application context programatically in my mail class.

We are using Spring MVC in this project.

I´ll illustrate what I want with an example.

In our JSPs, we have snippets like this:

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript">
```

In this context, `request.getContextPath()` will resolve to 
http://localhost:8080/applicationName

This is what I want for my mail class aswell.

I attempted to implement ServletContextAware in my class, 
thinking I would be able to use `servletContext.getContextPath()` with similar results. But this statement only resolves to /applicationName

So to my question: 
How can I get the full host and context (http://localhost:8080/applicationName) in my mail class? Is there some other interface than ServletContextAware that I can use? Help please :-)

Regards
Daniel

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343634/get-server-name-from-postconstruct-method-in-a-spring-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did search before posting, but apparently not hard enough. This exact same question has been asked (and answered) already.

[Finding your application's URL with only a ServletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675730/finding-your-applications-url-with-only-a-servletcontext)